# When do we know that SSL is used to full extent?

Tags: php, ssl

The application I'm developing (simple system with register/login, 1 DB, CRUD) is located on a domain that has an SSL certificate (the padlock appears when pasting a URL with https). Does that mean that SSL will be used and I don't need to add any code to my application?

Comment: Well, try pasting a URL without `https://`. Are you redirected to the HTTPS version? Also, [try this test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html).

Comment: No, it doesn't mean only SSL will be used. Is your site also accessible when calling URLs from `http://` instead of `https://`? Typically, it is the web server's job to manage this via configuration and URL rewriting, not your application code's responsibility.

Comment: Not yet. Ok, so as I understood all I need to do is to disable access from `http://` and instead redirect `http://` requests to `https://`?

Comment: That’s not necessarily all, but it’s the most important start, yes.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, not really, it's up to the application to make sure that it uses `https://` links. URL rewriting doesn't help (and assuming this sort of server setting will solve this problem can still make connections vulnerable to downgrade attacks). (More details [here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/28443/11628)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't know for sure server side whether SSL is being used. Sure, you can set your web server to deny HTTP connexions or to redirect them to HTTPS (this is typically set in the web server, not in the application). But unless you require your clients to provide a certificate, this setting won't prevent a man-in-the-middle attack. An attacker can set a proxy that accepts only HTTP connexions from the client, and then connects to the server through HTTPS.

See [sslstrip](http://www.thoughtcrime.org/software/sslstrip/) for an actual, successful, implementation of this attack.

Comment: +1 One way to mitigate this (without client-cert) is to use HSTS, if the browser supports it.